# Meteor handle returned database field value as variable

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, nosql

I'm wondering if it's possible to assign fields to variables in Meteor

What I want to achieve is to truncate a string that is a post title coming from Mongo.

This is what I've tried so far, without any luck:

```
classified: function() {
    return Ads.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
},
truncTitle: function() {
    return classified.title.substring(1, 4);
}
```

Is there any way to assign field values to variables?

Thanks

Comment: you mean, you want to use that value in a session variable or using it in a template helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a transform:

```
classified: function() {

    var transform = function(doc) {
        doc.truncTitle = doc.title.substring(1, 4)
        return doc;
    }

    return Ads.find({}, {transform: transform, sort: {createdAt: -1}});
}
```

Then use `{{truncTitle}}` in your `{{#each}}` loop.